# symfony3 ManytoMany join request

Tags: php, symfony

I got 2 entities - `Products` and `Region`. They have `ManytoMany` relation and are connected with the 3rd entity `Product_region`. Its code is as follows:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Product_region
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="product_region")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Product_region
{
/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var \AppBundle\Entity\Products
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Products")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="product_id", referencedColumnName="row_id")
 * })
 * 
 */
private $productid;

/**
 * @var \AppBundle\Entity\Region
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Region")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="region_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 * })
 */
private $regionid;

}
```

I need to download all `products` with its regions into one array to have something like:

```
[
 [0]=>[
  'name'=> 'product_1', 
  'regions=>[
     [0]=>['id'=>'1', 'name'=>'region_1'],
     [1]=>['id'=>'2', 'name'=>'region_2']...
  ]
 ],
 [1]=> ...
]
```

I try to do that with the following code:

```
$qb = $em->createQueryBuilder();
  $qb->select('p', 'pnr')
     ->from('AppBundle:Products', 'p')
     ->leftJoin('AppBundle:Product_region', 'pr', 'WITH', 'p = pr.productid')
     ->leftJoin('AppBundle:Region', 'pnr', 'WITH', 'pnr = pr.regionid');

  $res = $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
```

but if I try to `var_dump($res)` it hangs the browser and starts to transfer the  unlimited amount of data. Any ideas how to fix it would be welcome. Thank you.

Comment: Did you try `->getResult(Query::HYDRATE_ARRAY)`?

Comment: I tried `->getArrayResult()` but it failed and the result was the same.

Comment: Tip: don't use `var_dump()` with Doctrine entities or you'll have a bad time.  Instead use `\Doctrine\Common\Util\Debug::dump($res)`.  The 2nd parameter to that dump() function also takes in an integer for `$maxDepth` if you need

Comment: See this example. [Many-to-many association example in symfony](http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/toza/many-to-many-association-example-in-symfony). **Note:** If you are not hydrating the result properly and trying to dump the result, your computer/browser will hang/crash as the resulting object is massive.

Comment: I did almost as it is said in the article. All I`m trying to do is to download all the data from my DB into one array and use it